N8N + qdrant: working example in the documentation?
That might seem very simple.
I'm trying to replicate the Workflow 1 from qdrant-n8n documentation, but I encounter the following error:
Problem in node ‘Qdrant Vector Store‘
400 Bad Request: Wrong input: Not existing vector name error:


Any clue about how to solve this?
Thanks in advance for your help
The following is not included inqdrant-n8n documentation:

how to initialize a qdrant collection from qdrant dashboard, such that the collection is compatible with N8N?
workflow file?
and I didn't find those informations anywhere else online.

Here is how I created the collection in qdrant:

Here are some more details about the error:

Full workflow code:
{
  "name": "VanillaWorkflow",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "parameters": {
        "model": "text-embedding-3-small",
        "options": {}
      },
      "id": "12a2cf2a-1a58-431e-9c9e-18df40c6ab72",
      "name": "Embeddings OpenAI",
      "type": "@n8n/n8n-nodes-langchain.embeddingsOpenAi",
      "typeVersion": 1,
      "position": [
        1080,
        260
      ],
      "credentials": {
        "openAiApi": {
          "id": "tFhC2KmV4dSxIDlf",
          "name": "OpenAi"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "parameters": {
        "repository": "https://github.com/qdrant/demo-food-discovery",
        "additionalOptions": {}
      },
      "id": "fbea791d-6f7f-4524-8dad-2e71083cf6b9",
      "name": "GitHub Document Loader",
      "type": "@n8n/n8n-nodes-langchain.documentGithubLoader",
      "typeVersion": 1,
      "position": [
        1180,
        260
      ],
      "credentials": {
        "githubApi": {
          "id": "uBLBPG8XsplzEEl3",
          "name": "GitHub account"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "parameters": {
        "options": {}
      },
      "id": "9f5ed629-7f76-4991-ab10-630b94e62db9",
      "name": "Recursive Character Text Splitter",
      "type": "@n8n/n8n-nodes-langchain.textSplitterRecursiveCharacterTextSplitter",
      "typeVersion": 1,
      "position": [
        1320,
        420
      ]
    },
    {
      "parameters": {},
      "id": "48ed4863-dffd-4587-9385-932c8d888a74",
      "name": "When clicking \"Test workflow\"",
      "type": "n8n-nodes-base.manualTrigger",
      "typeVersion": 1,
      "position": [
        820,
        60
      ]
    },
    {
      "parameters": {
        "mode": "insert",
        "qdrantCollection": {
          "__rl": true,
          "value": "documents2",
          "mode": "list",
          "cachedResultName": "documents2"
        },
        "options": {}
      },
      "id": "d95c24d8-cb9a-4dae-af5f-a581c7453f8c",
      "name": "Qdrant Vector Store",
      "type": "@n8n/n8n-nodes-langchain.vectorStoreQdrant",
      "typeVersion": 1,
      "position": [
        1060,
        60
      ],
      "credentials": {
        "qdrantApi": {
          "id": "xU6ckdScUzDOhzdT",
          "name": "QdrantApi account"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "pinData": {},
  "connections": {
    "Embeddings OpenAI": {
      "ai_embedding": [
        [
          {
            "node": "Qdrant Vector Store",
            "type": "ai_embedding",
            "index": 0
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "GitHub Document Loader": {
      "ai_document": [
        [
          {
            "node": "Qdrant Vector Store",
            "type": "ai_document",
            "index": 0
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "Recursive Character Text Splitter": {
      "ai_textSplitter": [
        [
          {
            "node": "GitHub Document Loader",
            "type": "ai_textSplitter",
            "index": 0
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "When clicking \"Test workflow\"": {
      "main": [
        [
          {
            "node": "Qdrant Vector Store",
            "type": "main",
            "index": 0
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "active": false,
  "settings": {
    "executionOrder": "v1"
  },
  "versionId": "8d2b92dc-d47b-4575-b7b5-7dcf3dca39a3",
  "meta": {
    "templateCredsSetupCompleted": true,
    "instanceId": "2f70cd111ab80d00cdd02b4bc3bb9ec8acf888ed8ff50d1ba51efd710abc7661"
  },
  "id": "mocWTbbcEA6LcYMj",
  "tags": []
}


Others encountering similar issue, but their solution did not apply: https://github.com/orgs/qdrant/discussions/3213

It seems the collection is misconfigured. You don't need to explicitly create a collection.
The node automatically does so based on the embeddings.
You can try specifying a different collection name, which will be created by the node and data will be added into it.

Thanks a lot @Anush, setting a name of collection (which doesn't exist yet) solved the issue (a name of collection is required in the settings of the node Qdrant Vector Store)

I'd been looking for the same answer for 2 days, I searched through the documentation and finally came across this one which gave me a clue that I applied, without conviction.
My test is a made-up case but resembles the example in the documentation.
I'm using a different node because I'm loading a file from the local disk.
So, instead of the "Github Document Loader", I use a "Default Data Loader" in which I've added a property named "vector" with value "embeddings". (without quotation marks)
and it works.
Beforehand, I had tried in the qdrant dashboard to create a vector with a suitable name and parameters, without success.
My next step will be to understand why it worked, as I'd tried the same technique with other values ("text", collection name, etc.) without any convincing result.
Wishing you all the best for the rest of your tests

Hello JCK, @Anush gave the solution below :)
I'm interested in using the Default Data Loader as well. Would you mind sharing your example please?
